# Email notification snippet doesn´t display 2 out of 5 metakeys

Tags: php, wordpress, email, code-snippets

The following code sends a notification to the admin mail after every registration on the website:

```
function custom_registration_notification($user_id) {
    $user = get_userdata($user_id);
    $admin_email = 'admin@hl.de'; // E-Mail-Adresse, an die die Benachrichtigung gesendet werden soll
    $subject = 'Neue Registrierung auf www.hl.de';

    // Nutzerinformationen
    $username = $user->user_login;
    $user_email = $user->user_email;

    // Zusätzliche Felder aus Benutzerprofil abrufen
    $first_name = get_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', true);
    $last_name = get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_name', true);
    $tp_phone_number = get_user_meta($user_id, 'tp_phone_number', true);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'tp_phone_number', $tp_phone_number);
    $description = get_user_meta($user_id, 'description', true);
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'description', $description);



    // Check if fields are empty and set default values if needed
    if (empty($first_name)) {
        $first_name = 'N/A';
    }
    if (empty($last_name)) {
        $last_name = 'N/A';
    }
    if (empty($tp_phone_number)) {
        $tp_phone_number = 'N/A';
    }
    if (empty($description)) {
        $description = 'N/A';
    }

    $message = 'Ein neuer Benutzer hat sich auf der Website registriert:' . "\n\n";
    $message .= 'Vorname: ' . $first_name . "\n";
    $message .= 'Nachname: ' . $last_name . "\n";
    $message .= 'E-Mail: ' . $user_email . "\n";
    $message .= 'Telefonnummer: ' . $tp_phone_number . "\n";
    $message .= 'Unternehmen: ' . $description . "\n";

    wp_mail($admin_email, $subject, $message);
error_log('Custom Registration Error: ' . print_r($tp_phone_number, true));
}
add_action('user_register', 'custom_registration_notification');
```

Unfortunetly it displays just 3 out of 5 information. But in the backend all 5 fields are filled with information.

It looks like this:

Vorname: ErrorTest
Nachname: Test
E-Mail: 123@error.de
Telefonnummer: N/A
Unternehmen: N/A

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

I tried it with `update_user_meta($user_id, 'tp_phone_number', $tp_phone_number);` but it also doesn't work.

Comment: _"I tried it with `update_user_meta($user_id, 'tp_phone_number', $tp_phone_number);` but it also doesn't work."_ - well if you weren't able to _read_ anything into `$tp_phone_number` on the previous line, then this can hardly make any sense to begin with, can it?

Comment: The first three are "default" fields, whereas the latter two appear to be custom ones. So how _exactly_ did those get added to the user profile to begin with?

Comment: I added these two custom fields to the registration form. I used the same metakeys and they get added to the profile (i can see them in the backend)

Comment: Perhaps you need to find a "later" hook; https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/ says, _"Not all user meta data has been stored in the database when this action is triggered. For example, nickname is in the database but first_name and last_name are not (as of v3.9.1)"_ - regarding first and last name, it looks like that has changed by now, but it might still be true for any additional fields you added yourself.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the information is stored in the backend...

Comment: Just because you see it in the backend _after_ the user has registered, doesn't necessarily mean it is already present there at the time the `user_register` callback executes.